# Cuda Error at cuCtxCreate: Unknown error

Tags: cycles-render-engine, gpu

I am trying to get my dual GTX 1080 Ti working in Cycles, however no bingo. When I try to render a scene (just the box with nothing else in it) I get the error message “Cuda Error at cuCtxCreate: Unknown error”

I have tried using the 1080 ti, how ever still have the same issue. CPU rending is fine.
I am on 2.79b and all my windows drivers and nvidia drivers are upto date.

Are there any other logs that I can look at?

Below are my specs for the PC that I am using.

2 x Processor   Intel® Xeon® CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz, 2201 Mhz, 22 Core(s), 44 Logical Processor(s)
Installed Physical Memory (RAM) 512 GB
2 x Display NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1080 Ti

Comment: No one has any ideas?